# Rest Webservice call in AngularJS ( promise )

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory, angularjs-http

AngularJS : 1.4.X
Scenario 1: Works fine
Scenario 2: Throws 404 error on line xhr.send(isUndefined(post) ? null : post); in angular.js

I'm trying to add inbuilt angular cache to our existing app, As i mentioned in scenario 1 we consume rest call in factory 'restFactory' and inject the factory to controller 'bookController', the promise is resolved and data loads fine.

Factory: restFactory

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('myApp').factory("restFactory",['$http','confi', function($http,config){

    function getBooks (){  
       return $http.get(config.serverName+"bookshelf/rest/books/data/geRestBooks");
    }
    return {
        getBooks : getBooks
    };
}]);
})();
```

Controller: bookController

```
   $scope.getComicbooks = function() {
        restFactory.getBooks().then(function(response) {        
            $scope.names = response.data;
        }, function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;
            $scope.names = [];
        });
    };
```

Now in scenario 2, I changed the service call in factory to object with more details. But i get exception from controller while resolving the promise ( i have only added the changed code )

```
function getBooks (){  
   return $http.get({
   cache: true,
   method: 'GET',
   url : config.serverName+"bookshelf/rest/books/data/geRestBooks"
   });
}
```

ERROR: angular.js:10765 GET http://127.0.0.1:53814/views/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Network Tab:
[image]
In scenario#1 this would have been a method call getBooks

Comment: Where do you call  http://127.0.0.1:53814/views/ ?

Comment: @AdamWolski: I consume `bookController` in index page which is in views directory, but i when i added console.log it breaks before it resolves `restFactory.getBooks().then(function(response) {`.

Comment: What do you see in the network tab for that request?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship: updated

Comment: your urls don't even match here.  the first example has `config.serverName+"bookshelf/rest/books/data/geRestBooks"`, while the second has `config.serverName+"bookshelf/rest/books/data/getBooks"`

Comment: for that matter, neither of them match this error...

Comment: @Claies: typo, will update

Comment: The network tab should provide you with more information on the request and response than just what you posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to specify the method, then you should just use the `$http` constructor method, not the `get` method.

Instead of

```
function getBooks (){  
   return $http.get({
      cache: true,
      method: 'GET',
      url : config.serverName+"bookshelf/rest/books/data/geRestBooks"
   });
}
```

Try

```
function getBooks (){  
   return $http({
      cache: true,
      method: 'GET',
      url : config.serverName+"bookshelf/rest/books/data/geRestBooks"
   });
}
```

Comment: Excellent catch! The reason OP's code fails is because [`$http.get`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) expects the first argument to be a URL string. Since OP is passing an object, they get the string version of an object, ie `[object Object]`

Comment: Alternatively, OP could use `$http.get(config.serverName+"bookshelf/rest/books/data/geRestBooks", { cache: true })`

Comment: @Phil - I actually prefer your suggestion and was going to mention it, but figured I should stick to helping resolve the issue since I've been penalized for suggesting alternatives before.

Comment: It's hardly an alternative. Internally, `$http.get` just proxies through to `$http` with `method` pre-set and `url` added from the first argument. Feel free to add it to your answer :)